# Ampl syntax: return value at a specific position in set. AKA: use a set as an INDEX on another set

Tags: indexing, syntax, ampl

My question is this:
How can I use SUBSET (a discontinuous set) to refer to an **index** location in another set as opposed to an actual value? I see that ord() can be used to return the position of a value in a set, but I want the reverse of this...

---

my reason for needing this:

I have a model in which some of the set and data statements are roughly:

```
set ALL_TIME := {0..20000};
param DATA {ALL_TIME};      #read from file in later data statement;
set myTIME := {0...1000};
```

I am looping over the myTIME set and each time solving the model and then incrementing the start and end by 1: {1..1001}, {2..1002}, {3..1003}, etc.

I have another discontinuous set being read in from a file that looks something like this (yes below is bad syntax, the "...." is just there to mean that the pattern continues until it hits 1000 so I don't have to type it all) :

```
set SUBSET := {6,7,8,9,10, 16,17,18,19,20, 26,27.....}
```

Once myTIME increments such that it no longer contains "6", I get a subscript undefined error from a constraint which I understand to be because myTIME in this case is {7..1007} and thus in the following, tSUB=6 causes ALPHA[6] and is undefined:

```
subject to CONSTRAINT {tSUB in SUBSET}:
     ALPHA [tSUB] = ALPHA[last(tSUB)];
```

What I **want** is to be able to use SUBSET to always refer to the same index location of ALPHA, DATA, etc.
So:

```
SUBSET[0] (which equals 6) should always be the 6th value of for example DATA: 
{tSUB in SUBSET}: DATA[tSUB]. when tSUB is 0, I want the 6th value of DATA.
```

(I am new to Ampl and have a hard time wrapping my head around how indexing and sets work - if anything didn't make sense, please ask and I'll try to clarify. If you think it would be more helpful to see my actual code I'll try to sanitize the company data out and post it). Also, some of the code bits above have abysmal syntax. They are not copied from my code, just approximated to try to explain my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get i-th member of set `S` with `member(i, S)`, where `i` is a 1-based index and `S` is an ordered set. This is described in section [5.6 Ordered sets](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/08-sets1.pdf#page=12) of the AMPL book.